# Creating a .deb out of iOS app for Cydia repo release doesn't seem create proper .deb

Tags: ios, xcode, cydia

I have been developing an app for an iDevice, and I wanted to create a *.deb* file of my app, so I created a simple app in Xcode to test things out, but I am having difficulty creating the .deb file.

I did the following steps:

1) deleted the .DS_Store files, *$ rm -rf .DS_Store*
2) *$ dpkg-deb -b  ~/repo/debs*

When it creates the *.deb* file it is only 16KB which I know the test app should be a little bigger.

The directory structure for the app is as follows:

```
+- MyProgram
 +- Applications
 | +- MyProgram.app 
 | +- Info.plist 
   | +- MyProgram 
   | +- icon.png 
+- DEBIAN 
| +- control 
+- System 
 +- Library 
  +- LaunchDaemons 
   +- com.saurik.MyProgram.plist
```

I didn't include a *com.saurik.MyProgram.plist* file because I didn't see a file resembling one in the build directory, when I built the app in Xcode.

Basically the app is a simple viewcontroller with a label.  The app does contain a *.storyboard* file if that makes a difference.

Comment: do you have a com.saurik.MyProgram.plist file, or don't you?  please describe your problem carefully, otherwise it's pretty hard to help you.  also, are you sure the directory structure above is **exactly** what you're using?

Comment: @Nate, I got this working, the com.saurik.MyProgram.plist is not necessary for creating a .deb file for release on Cydia.

Comment: Yeah, you would only need such a file if your app is supposed to run as a launch daemon.  If it's a normal app, don't include the `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/` folder.  But, the folder hierarchy above that was wrong, too.  For example, `MyProgram` should be under the `MyProgram.app` folder, not parallel to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working, and created a shell script in the process.  The shell script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Update Repo Script Started"

cd ~/Projects/<ProjectName>

ldid -S app/<Project.app>/<Project>

cp -R app/<Project.app> ~/packages/<Project>/Applications/

cd ~/packages

echo $PWD

dpkg-deb -b <Project> ~/repo/debs/

cd ~/repo

dpkg-scanpackages debs / > Packages

bzip2 -fks Packages

cd ..

ssh -n <host> 'rm -rf /path/to/your/repo'

scp -r repo <host>:/home/<user>/www/

echo "Repo Updated"
```